# Prove that limit of sequence $3^{2n}$ diverge to $\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification

Anyone can check my proof and point the mistake ?

For every $M> 0$ It must has n that $3^{2n}\geq M$ then $n\geq K$

consider $3^{2n}>M$ then $3^{n}> M$

That is

$$ \frac{1}{M}> \frac{1}{3^{n}} \Leftrightarrow 3^{n}> M$$

By transitivity

$$3^{2n}> 3^{n},3^{n}> M \Rightarrow 3^{2n}> M$$ 
for every $n\geq K$

therefore it diverge to $\infty $

Comment: Several things are wrong. First you must say for every $M>0$ there must be $n$ such that $n\ge K$ implies $3^{2n}\ge M$ not the other way around. Also $3^{2n}>M$ does not imply $3^n>M$ (the other way around is correct). You assumed $3^{2n}>M$ to prove the same statement...

Comment: For correct way just notice that $3^{2n}>M \impliedby 2n>\log_{3} M$

Comment: ok thank I got that  ^ ^